# Expectation of evenly distributed bimoial distribution

Tags: statistics

> "An assembly line involves sampling 150 finished items per day and
>   counting F, the number of defective items. The probability of a
>   defective item is p. However, p also varies from day to day and is
>   assumed to have a uniform distribution on the interval from 0 to 1/3. 
>   What is the expected number of defective items?"

I know that

$$E(F)=\sum F_i Prob(F_i)$$
F can run from 0 to 150. However, the Probability of all the $F_i$ are 0, so I need to integrate Prob of Fi using the binomial distribution.
$$Prob(F_i)=\frac{N!}{F_i!(N-F_i)!}p^{F_i}(1-p)^{N-F_i}$$ 
But then p has a range, so how do I account for this?

Comment: Use Law of Iterated Expectation: $E[F]= E[E[F\mid p]]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X \mid p \sim \mathrm{Binomial}(150,p)$, where $p \sim \mathrm{Uniform}(0,1/3)$.  Then we want the unconditional expectation of $X$:  $$\mathrm{E}[X] = \mathrm{E}[\mathrm{E}[X \mid p]],$$ where the inner expectation is taken with respect to the *conditional* random variable $X \mid p$, and the outer with respect to $p$.  That is to say, $$\mathrm{E}[X \mid p] = 150p,$$ since the expected number of failures assuming $p$ is fixed is $150p$.  Then the expectation of $150p$ is given by $$\mathrm{E}[150p] = 150\mathrm{E}[p] = \frac{150}{6} = 25,$$ since the expectation of a continuous uniform distribution on $(a,b)$ is simply $(a+b)/2$.

---

Note that the calculation of the expected value is easy because of its linearity.  If we were asked to compute the *variance* of the unconditional distribution of $X$, then that requires the formula $$\begin{align*} \mathrm{Var}[X] &= \mathrm{E}[\mathrm{Var}[X \mid p]] + \mathrm{Var}[\mathrm{E}[X \mid p]] \\ &= \mathrm{E}[150p(1-p)] + \mathrm{Var}[150p] \\ &= 150\mathrm{E}[p-p^2] + 150^2 \mathrm{Var}[p] \\ &= 150\left(\tfrac{1}{6} - \mathrm{E}[p^2]\right) + 150^2 \left( \mathrm{E}[p^2] - \mathrm{E}[p]^2\right), \end{align*}$$ and we would need to calculate the second raw moment of $p$:  $$\mathrm{E}[p^2] = \int_{p=0}^{1/3} 3p^2 \, dp = \frac{1}{27},$$ hence $\mathrm{Var}[X] = 150(\tfrac{1}{6} - \tfrac{1}{27}) + 150^2(\tfrac{1}{27} - \tfrac{1}{36}) = \tfrac{2050}{9}.$

Further, if we wanted to compute the unconditional distribution of $X$, this requires a different approach:  $$\Pr[X = x] = \int_{\phi=0}^{1/3}\Pr[X = x \mid p = \phi]f_p(\phi) \, d\phi = \int_{\phi=0}^{1/3} 3\binom{150}{x} \phi^x (1-\phi)^{150-x} \, d\phi.$$  Unfortunately, this integral does not have an elementary closed form for general $x$:  it is an incomplete beta function.  For a *fixed* integer $x$ between $0$ and $150$, however, we can calculate the integral by polynomial expansion to obtain a rational number.